# Wrapping JSON payload with key in EmberJS

Tags: json, codeigniter, ember.js

Ok basically I am sending a POST request with some JSON payload in it to Codeigniter. I use RESTAdapater. JSON get sent there with no key, so I have no access to it.

Here is model:

```
App.Bookmark = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr("string"),
    url : DS.attr("string")
});
```

Here is controller:

```
App.BookmarksNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    save: function(){
        this.get("model.transaction").commit();
        this.get("target").transitionTo("bookmarks");
    }
});
```

In REST implementation in CI that I use standard way to access the post request is `$this->input("key")`. But when the above request is generated, only raw JSON data is sent. Therefore I don't seem to have a way to reference it in any way.

Take this example:

```
function post(){
    $this->response(var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input")),200);
}
```

Gives me this output:

```
string(48) "{"bookmark":{"title":"sdffdfsd","url":"sdfsdf"}}"
```

what I would like to see is:

```
string(48) payload="{"bookmark":{"title":"sdffdfsd","url":"sdfsdf"}}"
```

Then is server I would be able to access this JSON with something like `$this->post("payload").`

So 1 of 2. Anyway to wrap the JSON payload with key? Or anyway to access raw JSON data in CI with no key available??

Comment: $array = json_decode($payload); will give you an array with the items on it so you can reference them the way you want.

Comment: why do you not access it without key? $this->post

Comment: well probably because of underlying implementation in PHP, it doesn;t get registered in $_POST array if its not a valid query string or something like that.

Would it be bad idea to access the JSON with just file_get_contents("php://input")??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out myself (or rather read properly the examples).

When using Adam Whitney's fork of Phil Sturgeons [REST controller for CodeIgniter](https://github.com/awhitney42/codeigniter-restserver-resources) the JSON payload will be available in `$this->_post_args`. And in the underlying implementation he uses my already mentioned `file_get_contents("php://input")`.

EDIT: Same convention applies for other type of requests as well, for example DELETE request data will be available in `$this->_delete_args`. Or `$this->_args` is the "magic" place where all types of args can be found.